# Http data caching in android application

Tags: android, performance, caching, https

I have searched for this but didn't got any appropriate ans. I am developing a social android app in which some feed data need to cache show that when user open this app and there is no network connection won't get blank screen. what is the best and fast access way to cache  web data.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely parse the HTTP data into your own objects. So the question will rather be how to serialize these objects, and save them. These are the most common formats for object serialization:

- a plain file, such as in XML or JSON format
- a SQLite database
- SharedPreferences (as a Set, so this will only work well if the order of the strings is able to be rebuilt later, such as them being in alphabetical order)

(These points look common, eh, @CommonsWare ;)

Facebook, for example, uses an SQLite database, at least for their iOS app.

Comment: thanks for reply. I now there are list of option available but I want to know about which one will be best among them.For example how Facebook does the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using retrofit then you can use cache interceptors.

1. Firstly declare cache memory size

   int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // this is 10MB

Then create a cache object

```
Cache provideCache(MyApplication context) {
Cache cache = null;
try {
    cache = new Cache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "http-cache"), cacheSize);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Cache", "Error in creating  Cache!");
}

return cache;
```

}

Then create 2 network interceptors for HTTP client ( One for Online, one for No network case)

```
Interceptor provideOnlineInterceptor(MyApplication context) {
return chain -> {
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    CacheControl cacheControl;
    if (Utilities.isNetworkConnected(context)) {
        cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder().maxAge(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    } else {
        cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxStale(7, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build();
    }

    return response.newBuilder()
            .removeHeader(HEADER_PRAGMA)
            .removeHeader(HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL)
            .header(HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControl.toString())
            .build();

};

Interceptor provideOfflineInterceptor(MyApplication context) {
return chain -> {
    Request request = chain.request();

    if (!Utilities.isNetworkConnected(context)) {
        CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                .maxStale(7, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build();

        request = request.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader(HEADER_PRAGMA)
                .removeHeader(HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL)
                .cacheControl(cacheControl)
                .build();
    }

    return chain.proceed(request);
};
```

Create Httpclient

```
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(MyApplication context) {
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(provideOfflineCacheInterceptor(context))
        .addNetworkInterceptor(provideCacheInterceptor(context))
        .cache(provideCache(context));
return httpClient.build();
```

}

Then finally add this httpclient to Retrofit instance

```
Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient client,Gson gson) {
return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)
      .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
      .client(client)
      .build();
```

}

Hope this will work.
Please go through below link for more detail
[Network caching using interceptors](https://medium.com/mindorks/displaying-cache-data-or-offline-mode-support-in-android-application-aca5abd76644)

Comment: Link only answers are highly discouraged! Please take some time in explaining what the link does!